# What is the best way to operate with rate-limited API?

Tags: php, json, design-patterns

There is a HTTP API for interfacing with different data structures on a server. JSON data can be pulled using get method, changed using update method, created using add method or deleted using delete method. The API is rate limited: this means you cannot use it for every small action you do in code, actions must be grouped and pushed with big chunks. Also, I cannot push the whole data structure back, rate limiting will prevent that - I need to push changes only. What is the best way to recreate the data structure using the API, operate on a local copy, and push changes only?

Basically, I want to get several sets of JSON objects, decode them into PHP objects or arrays (or should I use a database?), operate with local copy of these objects - update, add and remove. Then appropriate API methods should be called: one "add" call containing new objects, one "delete" containing IDs of objects to delete and so on.
It there a pattern name for that, that I can see a reference implementation, or maybe a ready to use library?
Thanks.

Currently on every action I'm pushing an object to a "changed objects" array, one for every type of action.

Comment: Maybe use a library to create a diff of the original, and your modified JSON? https://github.com/swaggest/json-diff

Comment: I suggest you create data structures that represent the json data you have, and also track changes since last save. They then provide a save-method, that look at the changes and make an api call bundling all the changes. WIth nested data, this has to be done recursively.